# Execute a command from Ruby and retrieve STDOUT and STDERR

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby executable that executes a system command.  I need the following behavior:

1. The STDOUT and STDERR from the sub command should display in real time (as if I had executed the sub command directly from the command line).
2. Just before, my executable ends, I'd like to retrieve all the content that was added to STDOUT and STDERR so I can inspect it.

**What's the best way to make this work?**  I've used `capture3` in the past to execute a command, and get the STDOUT/STDERR, but `capture3` suppresses the  output from the terminal.  I've used backticks and `system` before, but they only let me easily access STDOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the stdout and stderr handles returned by `Open3.popen3` and re-print them as they happen while also collecting.

For your convenience, here's a complete `Runner` class I had laying around:

```
require 'open3'

class Runner
  attr_reader :cmd, :exit_status, :stdout, :stderr

  # Run a command, return runner instance
  # @param cmd [String,Array<String>] command to execute
  def self.run(*cmd)
    Runner.new(*cmd).run
  end

  # Run a command, raise Runner::Error if it fails
  # @param cmd [String,Array<String>] command to execute
  # @raise [Runner::Error]
  def self.run!(*cmd)
    Runner.new(*cmd).run!
  end

  # Run a command, return true if it succeeds, false if not
  # @param cmd [String,Array<String>] command to execute
  # @return [Boolean]
  def self.run?(*cmd)
    Runner.new(*cmd).run?
  end

  Error = Class.new(StandardError)

  # @param cmd [String,Array<String>] command to execute
  def initialize(cmd)
    @cmd = cmd.is_a?(Array) ? cmd.join(' ') : cmd
    @stdout = +''
    @stderr = +''
    @exit_status = nil
  end

  # @return [Boolean] success or failure?
  def success?
    exit_status.zero?
  end

  # Run the command, return self
  # @return [Runner]
  def run
    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
      until [stdout, stderr].all?(&:eof?)
        readable = IO.select([stdout, stderr])
        next unless readable&.first

        readable.first.each do |stream|
          data = +''
          # rubocop:disable Lint/HandleExceptions
          begin
            stream.read_nonblock(1024, data)
          rescue EOFError
            # ignore, it's expected for read_nonblock to raise EOFError
            # when all is read
          end

          if stream == stdout
            @stdout << data
            $stdout.write(data)
          else
            @stderr << data
            $stderr.write(data)
          end
        end
      end
      @exit_status = wait_thr.value.exitstatus
    end

    self
  end

  # Run the command and return stdout, raise if fails
  # @return stdout [String]
  # @raise [Runner::Error]
  def run!
    return run.stdout if run.success?

    raise(Error, "command failed, exit: %d - stdout: %s / stderr: %s" % [exit_status, stdout, stderr])
  end

  # Run the command and return true if success, false if failure
  # @return success [Boolean]
  def run?
    run.success?
  end
end
```

With this you can do:

```
runner = Runner.new('ls -al')
runner.run
runner.success? # true if command was a success
runner.stdout # captured stdout
runner.stderr # captured stderr
```